# iOS compass navigation

Tags: ios, radians

I'm making an iPhone app for myself and colleagues for locating our devices.
It involves an compass that points to the north, and an needle that points to an given coordinate of an device.

However I'm having trouble with pointing the needle to the device.
I'm using the following code to try and create an 'triangle' and calculate the 'amount of radians' from the give North of the compass, so I can rotate the needle from the north to 'amount' offset from triangleC.

```
triangleA = curLocation.coordinate.latitude - setLocation.coordinate.latitude;
if(triangleA < 0) { east = NO; } else { east = YES; }
triangleB = curLocation.coordinate.longitude - setLocation.coordinate.longitude;
if(triangleB < 0) { north = NO; } else { north = YES; }

float tempC = pow(fabs(triangleA),2) + pow(fabs(triangleB),2);

triangleC = sqrtf(tempC);
```

However the triangleC does not contain an 'radians' between -360 and 360.

Together with this I have another question. Is there any private framework for getting current location of the user? Because the normal locationManager has a pretty big offset of min. 5 meters.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction for getting the right 'radians' from the north.

Comment: degrees are between 0 and 360. radians would be between 0 and 2π

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the pythagorean theorem you can use trig. First get the difference between the x and y of your points

```
float x = curLocation.coordinate.latitude - setLocation.coordinate.latitude;
float y = curLocation.coordinate.longitude - setLocation.coordinate.longitude;
```

Then use arctangent to get the angle.

```
float angle = atan2(y,x);
```

If you want all positve values, add this line:

```
if(angle<0) angle += 2.0*M_PI;
```

Then if you want to use degrees (0-360) instead of radians, convert using this line:

```
angle = angle * (180/M_PI);
```

And for your booleans. You will be pointing east when the angle is greater than 270° or less than 90°. You will be pointing north when the angle is between 0° and 180°.

```
east = (angle >= 270) || (angle <= 90);
north = (angle >= 0) && (angle <= 180);
```

Comment: Hmm that seems thats sounds promesing. I used the booleans to know which way the needle needs to turn.

Comment: From which point ate these radians taken from? From the north? I tried to create an triangle from curposition to setlocation and actually I assumed that the angle is relative from the north

Comment: the angle is between curlocation and setlocation

Comment: Yes I did understand that, but ita related from the north of the curlocation I asume?

Comment: It's related to the curlocation. Imagine the curlocation is the center of a circle. If setlocation is to the east the angle will be 0°, if setlocation is to the west the angle will be 180°

Comment: Hmmmz I see. So: needle rotation will be: currentheading + 90 + angle between locations? (I am drawing this needle on top pf normal compass that heads to the north)

Comment: the angle is the angle the needle will have to point from curlocation to setlocation

Comment: Ill play around with this tomorrpw as I dont think I can formulate my question better in English at the moment.aybe its the beer ;) ill let u know